# How to build .exe in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#

I used visual studio 2012 to create project and now i want to build that project to .exe file. what do i must do?

Comment: You must understand how compiling ad running an application works.

Comment: Press F6 to build your project

Answer (score 14):

If it's a [Console application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k1sx6ed2.aspx) or [Winform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx) or [WPF](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-002) application then you will get the executable by just building the application and it will be in your `yourApplicationPath/Bin/Debug`

**EDIT** (Based on the comment)

*You have to rephrase your question.* You need to see that:

[Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) will not ship with future versions of Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx)

> The Visual Studio setup projects will not ship again – Visual Studio 2010 was the
>   last release with support for it.  So, you’ll want to make plans to
>   migrate to something else.  Of course, I’d suggest looking into WiX,
>   and there are other options as well.  The MSDN page [Choosing a
>   Windows Installer Deployment Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) contains a table showing a
>   comparison of VS setup projects, WiX, and InstallShield Limited
>   Edition.

Comment: No, i mean i want to pack this project to build setup file

Comment: @walking, setup project has been abandoned in visual studuio 2012, see my edit.

Comment: @walking You must make **sure** that you are asking the question you intend to. You asked how to build the .exe, and that is what everyone answered.

Answer (score 5):

Select "Release" first from the Solution Configurations drop down box, otherwise your compiled/distributed executable will still be in debug mode. Not only does this effect performance but it has other negative effects.

Next go to the Build menu tab and select Build Solution (or press F6).

Then find your folder with your project and navigate to:
yourproject\bin\Release\

To fully Publish your program, select Publish from the Build tab and follow the Wizard. A Setup.exe will be created.

Answer (score 4):

The executable is built every time you run the project. You can find the `EXE` on the `bin\debug` folder located on your project folder.

```
..SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\
```

but if you mean that you want to create a `Setup File` or `MSI` (*or installers*), please see the article below

- [How to create a Setup package by using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: I use visual studio 2012 and seem it doesn't support create setup file?

Comment: oh VS2012 doesn't yet support setup projects.

Comment: so are there any sotfware support build setup file? :(

Comment: there are many softwares that you can find on the internet (*freewares and some are available to purchase*) that will help you create a setup file for your project.

Comment: can you suggest for me some software?

Answer (score 4):

Every time you compile and run your application, it creates an EXE which can be found in the following location:

> /path/to/project/bin/debug/myApp.exe

Within the menus of VisualStudio there is also an option toExport your project, which will build it to a specified path, as well, there is an option for creating an installer package if you so desire.

Answer (score 2):

does it have "Build" under Menu? if not, go to "tools"->"setting", choose "expert", then you should be able to see it now.

Comment: This is a very simple question. Previous versions of Visual Studio have a separate build button, VS2012 apparently does not. The answer is simple and was given in the statement "the executable is built every time you run the project". It is not difficult to tell what he is asking.  and has nothing to do with console app, winforms or WPF.